# Svn manage user, repositories, spaces using PHP

Tags: svn, svn-server

my whole experience with SVN is using tortoise SVN client, and have never setup the server. My boss wants me to setup a SVN server. Installing SVN server is no big deal, but the real problem is that he wants a PHP base script to control SVN users, their access, repositories/spaces etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that configuring apache basic authentication is a straightforward and easy way to manage svn users.

Here's a link that describes how to set it up:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html

Once you have that up, it shouldn't be too difficult to create a php script to manage the .htpasswd file. I did a quick google and here's a link that might help:

http://www.hawkee.com/snippet/7168/